# How does Cherenkov radiation destructively interferes and leaves only a radiation over a beamed cone?

Tags: particle-physics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, geometric-optics, cherenkov-radiation

I'm trying to understand the observations in IceCube Neutrino Observatory where they observe the Cherenkov radiation emitted by a charged particle in the ice. I know that applying the Huygens principle to spherically emitted radiation leads to a conic shaped radiation analogous to the Mach cone.

However, I don't intuitively understand why there is no radiation inside the cone, even the slightest. How does the radiation that only exists lies on a cone? Moreover, what is the thickness of this cone (or the thickness of the Cherenkov ring if a get a slice)?

So, to understand this I used Meep library to create Cherenkov radiation and see the ring expand over time on a fictitious wall. However, what I saw was there were also inner rings as well, although very dim compared to the major, outer ring (one example is here: https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ/#how-do-i-model-a-moving-point-charge).

I'm curious if this indeed exists, but practically not possible to observe.

Comment: This article  makes it clear http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2014/ph241/alaeian2/ . The angle is fixed for relativistic velocities.

Comment: @annav I'm sorry but this doesn't explain my question. This explains how the cone is formed. I don't deny the existence of the cone, I just don't see how to explain a complete destruction for the rest. I'm already familiar with the concept, including Frank-Tamm equation. But the question is, if there is no radiation other than over the beamed cone, then why do we see inner faint rings on Meep simulation? Am I missing something here? There is an example here with one component of E-field from the sides: https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ/#how-do-i-model-a-moving-point-charge

Comment: Does the frequency dependence of $n$ help? you certainly should get more than just a ring - because the index of refraction depends on frequency, and therefore you get different cone angles for different frequencies (that's kind of a handwavy way of putting it). Maybe if your detector only measures light of certain frequencies you'd only see one cone? All just speculation.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen Thank you! That is what I think as well. However, in every article, or in every meeting, people who work on this imply that there is only a Cherenkov ring visible (or I just get them wrong). And I'm trying to understand why. Maybe technical problems with observing the inner rings?

Comment: @AndrewChristensen from the link "In most cases, the second term is negligible, and the angle of the emitted photon can be approximated as cosθ ≅ c/(n u), where "..." For relativistic particles, the Cherenkov radiation occurs at a fixed angle. For non-relativistic particles however, the above arguments are not held accurately.There the radiation is mainly caused by the different polarization dipoles of the medium in front and back of the moving particle. It should be mentioned that most materials are dispersive, i.e. their refractive index varies with frequency. "

Comment: "Therefore the photons of different energy are scattered in various angles." these come from discussing Fig, 2.

Comment: @annav Thanks for emphasizing that! Is that imply that for IceCube, the second and other terms are negligible due to the scattering and reflection in ice? Or in other words, if one would have a perfectly uniform dielectric material, the other rings would be observable? Since I don't work in this field, I do not know the numbers or the actual observations that IceCube has. Maybe it is possible to observe but just not relevant information for them and they ignore it? Because I have never seen this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: The particles incoming and their interaction studied in the esperiment are certainly in the relativistic range so the higher frequency terms can be ignored and only the cone used to estimate the momenta and ernergies.

Comment: @annav I'm sorry, I'm confused about that. What PMT measures is brightness and I'm trying to understand whether that brightness includes photons from n-order ring. Also, in Meep simulation, I use the relativistic range that exactly matches the variables there (also relativistic for the example in the link). However, I do see E-field in the result. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PositiveNeutron  . I expect that cascades of lower energy particles will have been simulated, and those will give the rings you worry about.   look how complicated and developed over time  the icecube monte carlo is. "PISA was written by and for the IceCube Collaboration for analyses employing the IceCube Neutrino Observatory, " https://github.com/icecube/pisa .